# Как в svg сделать текст параллельный к отрезку?

Tags: php, svg

Пишу небольшой скрипт для визуализации графов и там нужно дать названия ребрам (мы знаем начальную и конечную точки ребра). Пытался сделать это с помощью defs и path, но не получилось.

Comment: svg свой покажите ...`php` тут не при чём

Comment: Никита Фаст, у меня вперемешку php c svg

Comment: Нам известны координаты начальной точки A(x,y) и  конечной B(x,y)
<defs>
 <path id='textpath' fill='none' stroke='#000000' d='M140,100c0,0,50,50,50,50c50'/>  
</defs> 
<use xlink:href='#textpath'/>
 <text x='20' y='50'>
 <textPath xlink:href='#textpath'>часть</textPath>
</text>'

Answer (score 0):

```html
<text x='228' y='228' transform='rotate(45)'>часть</text
```